# Do we need measurable functions when we consider almost everywhere convergence in measure theory?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, definition

I know this definition of almost everywhere convergence:

> If $f_n$ and $f$ are measurable functions defined on a measure space $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$, we say that $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere (a.e.) if there exists a set $E\in\Sigma$ with $\mu(E)=0$ such that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in S\setminus E$.

**My questions**

- Do we really want the functions be measurable?
- Or, do we only need a measure on $S$ that can be associated with sets and then we would be fine?
- If we do not consider measurable functions though, how do we define convergence?

Comment: The notion of a.e. convergence is defined (like you did) for *any* functions (not necessarily measurable) on a measure space.

Comment: @Anne Bauval: So in no circumstances we need the functions be measurable? Then, can we safely say $f_n \to f$ without being concerned about their measurability?

Comment: @Anne Bauval: Do we really need a measure space or only a measure suffices? In other words, "We say that $f_n$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere (a.e.) if there exists a set $E$ with $\mu(E)=0$ such that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x \notin E$.''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions $f_n,f$ do not need to be measurable.

But a [measure space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space) $(S,\Sigma,\mu)$ is necessary because a [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) $\mu$ is only defined on some [σ-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) $\Sigma$ on a set $S.$

[$f_n\to f$ $\mu$-a.e.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostEverywhereConvergence.html) iff there exists a set $E\in\Sigma$ such that $\mu(E)=0$ and $\forall x\in S\setminus E\quad f_n(x)\to f(x).$

So, you don't need that the set $\{x\in S\mid f_n(x)\to f(x)\}$ belongs to $\Sigma:$ you only need it to be a subset of some element of $\Sigma$ of $\mu$-measure $0$ (i.e. you only need it to be an element of $\tilde\Sigma$ of $\tilde\mu$-measure $0,$ where $\tilde{}$ refers to the [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure)).

Comment: @Sepide Done. You can now delete your comment here.